# How to control web-form buttons availability

Tags: javascript, webforms

I have a web-form with text fields. I want to make form buttons available only under certain conditions. When text fields are filled in.

Below there is my javascript code, but it does not work as expected.

What did I miss there?

Thank you.

```
function validate(input, name) {
    if(name=='name') {
        if(input==null || input=='') {
            document.getElementById('nameDiv').style.visibility='visible';
            document.getElementById('next').disabled='disabled';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('nameDiv').style.visibility='hidden';
            var emailField = document.getElementByID('email').value;
            if(emailField!="" || emailField!=null) {
                document.getElementById('next').disabled='';
            }
        }
    }

    if(name=='email') {
        if(input==null || input=='') {
            document.getElementById('emailDiv').style.visibility='visible';
            document.getElementById('next').disabled='disabled';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('emailDiv').style.visibility='hidden';
            var nameField = document.getElementByID('name').value;
            if(nameField!="" || nameField!=null) {
                document.getElementById('next').disabled='';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try With this...

```
document.getElementById('next').disabled= false;
document.getElementById('next').disabled=true;
```

Comment: i set an alert command after var nameField = document.getElementByID('name').value;, but it does not run it.

Comment: I think there is a syntax error.. use this... var nameField = document.getElementById('name').value;

Comment: after filling in one text field, why does it allow me to submit the form?

Comment: Use return false after document.getElementById('nameDiv').style.visibility='visible';
document.getElementById('next').disabled='disabled';

Comment: It still allows me to click the button, and when i show the value, it shows it as blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the below two lines

```
if(emailField!="" || emailField!=null) {
if(nameField!="" || nameField!=null) {
```

like

```
if(emailField!="" && emailField!=null) {
if(nameField!="" && nameField!=null) {
```